# Error when going to a MVC view - The type or namespace name 'UserModel' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I go to the view User/Add in a browser, I get the following message -

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UserModel' does not exist in the namespace 'CRM.Core.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**View**

```
@model CRM.Core.Models.UserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>UserModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber)
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

**UserController**

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _userService.Add(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
namespace CRM.Core.Models
{
    public class UserModel : IUserModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Employee Number")]
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does adding `@using CRM.Core.Models;` to your View helps ?

Comment: Just tried that now and it hasn't worked

Comment: Assuming project is compiled and class is public...try with `global::CRM.Core.Models.UserModel`, just in case you have some namespace with duplicated names...

Comment: if your models are in a separate assembly, ensure it is built properly and referenced properly.

Comment: All seems to be referenced Ok and have done rebuild, clean etc. @AdrianoRepetti where would your suggestion go? Never seen that before.

Comment: In `@model global::CRM.Core.Models.UserModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what happened but I simply restarted the PC and rebuilt again. All seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **referenced model was compiling into exe** (Console Application) and ASP.NET do not like that kind of model.
So I had to create model in different assembly - (class library project) and reference it to the view.

That made it work.